# What are the ways of selecting element from auto-suggestion dropdown?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

1. Typing into the input field using sendkeys.
2. Auto-suggestion comes. The html element is as follows:

   `<div angucomplete-alt id="ac-{{row.RowId}}" placeholder="Search materials..." maxlength="50" pause="100" selected-object="selectedCon" ng-click="selectedConRow(row)" local-data="materialsConsumables" search-fields="MaterialName" title-field="MaterialName" initial-value="row.materialSelected" minlength="1" input-class="autocomplete" match-class="highlight"></div>`
3. Collecting all the suggestions into a “List” and selecting one of the elements when match occurs with my desired string.
4. Value is selected and populated into the input field
5. Fills all other mandatory fields
6. Clicks “Submit”. But error showing that this input field is empty though it has a value. (P.S.: manually it works, there’s no problem with the application itself.)

Code::

```
String producttoSelect = "0007950137 - BSS 500ML GLASS -CDN";

WebElement ConProduct1 = objDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class=\"con_Material ng-isolate-scope\"]/div/input"));
    ConProduct1.sendKeys("0007950137 - BSS 500ML GLASS -CDN");

    try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    List<WebElement> productList = objDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class=\"con_Material ng-isolate-scope\"]/div/div"));
    for (WebElement optionP : productList) {
                    System.out.println(optionP.getText());
                    if (optionP.getText().equals(producttoSelect)) {
                                    System.out.println("Trying to select Product: " + optionP.getText());
                                    optionP.click();
                                    break;
                    }
    }
```

Comment: The element is like this: 
<div angucomplete-alt id="ac-{{row.RowId}}" placeholder="Search materials..." maxlength="50" pause="100" selected-object="selectedCon" ng-click="selectedConRow(row)" local-data="materialsConsumables" search-fields="MaterialName" title-field="MaterialName" initial-value="row.materialSelected" minlength="1" input-class="autocomplete" match-class="highlight">
</div>

Comment: after selecting auto-option then click somewhere out side and try. may helps

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thread.sleep, try using Explicit wait until the list is populated:

```
By aaa = By.xpath("//*[@class=\"con_Material ng-isolate-scope\"]/div/div");

        List<WebElement> suggestList = 
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(aaa));
```

Comment: I implemented this, but the actual problem is though the value is selected successfully, at the time of submission error is coming saying value missing.